# How to enter a Polish l in acmart document class?

Tags: libertine, acm, polish

I must use the `acmart` package for the paper. Writing "Micha{\l}{}", I obtain a space before "l" in the output pdf file: "Micha l".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\begin{document}
Micha{\l}.
\end{document}
```

Minimal document showing the problem is with `libertine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

Micha\l

\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue is not specific to `acmart`: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{libertine}\begin{document}Micha\l\end{document}` has the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I already wrote Bob Tennent.  See the discussion at https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/91

Comment: It's not specific to libertine either.  Any of the fonts whose support files were generated by autoinst will not support \l and \L in OT1 encoding.  The file fontools_ot1.enc is responsible.

Comment: Another workaround is to change the font encoding to T1 for `\l` and `\L`:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble

I will correct this problem in the next release of acmart.

Update:  https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/91